# Java spring configuration properties with fields instead of methods

Tags: java, spring

Have the following code:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config/application.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public class Example
{
    private boolean _works;
    public void setWorks( boolean newValue )
    {
        _works = newValue;
    }
    public boolean getWorks()
    {
        return _works;
    }
    public boolean doesntWork;
}
```

one configuration setting works, the other doesn't.   Is there any way of making it work?   Writing getters and setters makes me feel like I need a shower, and from the documentation, it looks like a field based property should actually work?

Comment: You should look into lombok, you can automatically have it generate getters and setters for your fields.

Comment: I think you are talking about `@Value`. here is good reference : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: @daniu ha.   I just had a discussion earlier today asking people to remove Lombok - it’s the existence of the methods I have a problem with, not typing them.

Comment: @NikolayRusev cool. Thanks.  Will try

Comment: If you want to use `@ConfigurationProperties` yes you need getter/setter. I you use `@Value` you can do without, however that makes `@ConfigurationProperties` useless again. Another thing (unrelated your `getWorks` should be named `isWorks()` instead. that is the convention for a primitvate `boolean` NOT a `Boolean`!).

Comment: thanks all - @value worked for me - no more getters/setters/issers - I'm happy!